# How do I move an item to an empty list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm working with a demo of two sortable jquery lists... but have a problem when one list is empty, I can no longer drag items onto it, because there is nothing there to drop on.  I tried adding space to the margin, padding and line-height of the ul, but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

```
<style type="text/css">
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
    }).disableSelection();
});
</script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the dropOnEmpty property to true. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#empty-lists for more information.

Comment: Thanks - that works.  I hate it when I search for something and the answer was on the same page :)

Comment: haha, It is funny, Ok, I have a question for you , What if the source is the draggable . It does't have the `dropOnEmpty` property. thanks.

Answer (score 35):

Frederik's answer didnt work for me

solution for me was to add a `min-height` to the empty `ul`

ref: http://rolleys.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/cant-get-jquery-sortable-to-drop-on-to-empty-lists/

Comment: Saved me. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: This worked for me.. I would still like to know why? I get that an empty list has a height of 0 and so it's not rendered visually. However shouldn't it still be able to be interacted with?

Comment: @kusudu94 when dragging a DOM element, the script tries to identify where in the DOM it has been dragged to, by checking what other elements it intersects with. The dragged element will never intersect with the target list if it has height=0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if by the time of question and the answers this was available, but as 2018 you can use the option `placeholder` and problem solved! (with little help of css)

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-placeholder