# jQuery UI sortable drag drop to empty list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following empty list:

```
<ul class="sortable_list">
  <p><a>Add new item</a></p>
</ul>
<ul class="sortable_list">
  <li class="sortable_item">
    AAA
  </li>
  <li class="sortable_item">
    BBB
  </li>
  <p><a>Add new item</a></p>
</ul>
```

And the following script:

```
$(".sortable_list").sortable({
  items: "li.sortable_item",
  connectWith: ".sortable_list",
  axis: "y",
  cursor: "move",
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  revert: "140",
    update: function() {
        alert('hehe');
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

The 1st `ul.sortable_list` is empty. When I drag the `li.sortable_item` from the 2nd `ul.sortable_list` to the 1st `ul.sortable_list`, the `li` item can be put below the `p`, which is not something I want. I want it to always be above `p`.

But, if I drag-drop the 2nd `ul.sortable_list` items within the same list, it can't go below the `p` which is exactly what I wanted.

How should I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336285/how-do-i-move-an-item-to-an-empty-list-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must follow the convention from the `.sortable()`.

Change the markup to this:

```
<ul class="sortable_list">

</ul>
<p><a>Add new item</a></p>

<ul class="sortable_list">
  <li class="sortable_item">
    AAA
  </li>
  <li class="sortable_item">
    BBB
  </li>
</ul>
<p><a>Add new item</a></p>
```