# Prevent click event on children of parent that is being dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a UL tag like this:

```
<ul ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <li class="item" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)">
        <div class="product-infos">
            <a href="javascript:;"></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to drag the whole LI element and drag to another UL element. Using javascript code:

```
<script>
    function allowDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    function dragStart(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target);
    }
    function dragging(event) {

    }
    function drop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, sometimes user's click the "div" element, other's click the "a" element. So, most of the times, the drag fails because I'm append the wrong child to the UL element.
I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

I want to be able to drag the whole element, wherever I click. I hope there's a solution.

Comment: Was there a reason you tagged this with jQuery?

Comment: Because I found a similar question with a jQuery way of doing it, but unsuccessful for my case.

Comment: I think your question should be: Prevent click event on children of parent that is being dragged

Comment: `I want to be able to drag the whole element, wherever I click. I hope there's a solution.` but your anchor tag is draggable too..

Comment: I changed the code, since I was testing a few options. Now should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery ui sortable, I've left your html with ondrag etc, but you dont need them

```js
$(function() {
     $(function() {
         $( "ul" ).sortable({
            connectWith: "ul"
         });
         $( "ul").sortable({
            connectWith: "ul",
            dropOnEmpty: false
         });

      });
  });
```

```css
ul{background-color:red;}
li{background-color:blue;}
a{background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">ul
    <li class="item">li
        <div class="product-infos">div
            <a href="javascript:;" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)">link</a>
        </div>
    </li>
  <li class="item">li
        <div class="product-infos">div
            <a href="javascript:;" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)">link</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">ul
    <li class="item">li
        <div class="product-infos">div
            <a href="javascript:;" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)">link</a>
        </div>
    </li>
  <li class="item">li
        <div class="product-infos">div
            <a href="javascript:;" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)">link</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works!
dropOnEmpty however didn't work alone, I added a min-height to the UL class and now it's perfect.
Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336285/how-do-i-move-an-item-to-an-empty-list-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might find the solution if you use event.currentTarget rather then event.target. Try it

Comment: why don't you try it, and if it works add it as an answer

Comment: @Billy main reason being is, because he did not provide the complete HTML structure for this to be tested in. If I could copy that to fiddle then I would post a fiddle answer as well.