# jquery ui cannot add li to sortable list after all li dragged out or removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a sortable set up like so:

```
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">First <a title='delete' class="itemDelete text-right"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li class="ui-state-default">Second <a title='delete' class="itemDelete"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li class="ui-state-default">Third <a title='delete' class="itemDelete"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
```

When I have dragged all the child elements, the `li`'s out of the `ul` I cannot add anymore since there needs to be one `li` in place for me to add. How can I make it so that even when it is empty I can still drag from sortable1 into this sortable2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move an item to an empty list using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336285/how-do-i-move-an-item-to-an-empty-list-using-jquery)

Comment: i also tried doing the min-height that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden "< li >" that can be used as a factory entity for you drag!

Comment: This is an idea i had thought of, but will do as last resort

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the dev tools console and witnessing the changes. I found that a simple 
 statement fixes this, even some words but a break is clean.

In dev tools after removing all elements i edited the html like so:

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
<br>
</ul>
```

Just add that br, you can even style on css... i think.